# Reload the comment count of Disqus

Tags: javascript, ajax, disqus

I am loading articles with AJAX. When I want to show their comment counts I use:

```
DISQUSWIDGETS.getCount();
```

This works. But when I load more articles and call the function again it does not show the comment counts of the articles. It also does not give any error. Is there a way to solve this problem in Javascript?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It might be something of a hack, but this works:

```
# Undefine disquswidgets to force a refresh also on ajax reload
window.DISQUSWIDGETS = undefined;
$.getScript("http://" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/count.js");
```

Basically you trick Disqus into believing that the typeof is undefined, which will make it execute the same code again as it does the first time it's run.

Comment: This works.  I'd be interested in a more elegant solution though :-)

Answer (score 5):

You should use this:

```
DISQUSWIDGETS.getCount({reset: true});
```

For more information, see [here](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/565624-tightening-your-disqus-integration)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Proper way to do it !

Comment: This isn't working for me, but the accepted answer is.

Comment: This indeed is the way to go, you just have to make sure that this particular function runs whenever ajax has completed loading the batch of elements.

Answer (score 0):

This was the error that annoys my console for a couple of months [console  error here for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hj3Fs.jpg)

Basically, you shouldn't run the getCount function whenever the DISQUSWIDGETS variable is undefined.

```
// call the count js first
<script async='async' id='dsq-count-scr' src='//yourwebsite.disqus.com/count.js' type='text/javascript'/>

<script type='text/javascript'>
// then the solution to reload disqus comment count safely
if(typeof DISQUSWIDGETS != "undefined") {                                                                                                                    
    DISQUSWIDGETS.getCount({ reset: true });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue and for the solution I found some good resources and solution from them.

For more [enter link description here](https://github.com/disqus/disqus-react/issues/30#issuecomment-505998737).This one works for me.

```
 window.DISQUSWIDGETS.getCount({ reset: true });
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33907622)