# Can't get all Disqus comment counts working

Tags: javascript, disqus

Building a Tumblr theme. Using Disqus for comments.

Loading in the Disqus JS like this (as they specify):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var disqus_shortname = 'myshortname';
    (function () {
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
    }());
</script>
```

Invoking the comment counts like this:

`<a href="http://blahblah.tumblr.com/post/83652751306/example#disqus_thread"></a>`

The problem I'm having is, **only some of the comment counts work on page load, and when I click to load in more posts they also don't have the comment count**.

I'm sure this has been asked many times, and I've tried various methods like this (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/disqus-dev/EGWWb27kvfQ) and this ([Reload the comment count of Disqus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21333184/reload-the-comment-count-of-disqus)).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, same thing is happening to me, did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not really. If you recently moved domain names you could try re-indexing the comments with the Domain Migration Wizard: https://USERNAME.disqus.com/admin/discussions/migrate/

Comment: hey @jody thanks for answering however i found out my issue was using the wrong paths, after fixing that the counts are working